Insecure form submission
I have CiviCRM running behind haproxy with a verified SSL connection. Whenever I submit forms in the CiviCRM interface, I'm told that the forms are insecure. I have verified that my https settings match any other sites that I'm using behind the same cert, and none of those have any issues.
If I enable the SSL settings in CiviCRM I then lose access to my site and have to go manually edit the settings.php file
EDIT:
I've attached a screenshot. As you can see (at the bottom), I'm accessing my code securely, but, if you look at the code, the submit/cancel buttons reference an insecure (http) connection
EDIT 2: I'm running on Joomla

Have you checked in civicrm.settings.php that your CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL setting is showing https ?

Yes. Verified as https

Got it working for the most part. Had to have an SSL backend-site as well as an SSL frontend.  Working now.
